# Authorize.net reseller API Login ID?

Tags: php, authorize.net

Moving into beta for a product I am pushing out I need to set up payments using Authorize.net gateway.

I am trying to wrap my head around "Authorize.net Resellers".

Currenty, I have a "test" API Login ID and Transaction Key. The payment process is working and fully implemented.

- Will I still be able to use the authorize.net payment API?
- If I purchase a reseller account do I get a new Login ID and Transaction Key?
- What things should I do to make transitioning from a test account to a real merchant account purchased through a reseller a painless
  process?
- Do I still have a portal that I will be able to access through authorize.net that will have a summary of all my transactions (do I
  lose any features by going through a reseller)?

I think the problem is I don't understand what an "authorize.net reseller" is.

Comment: Wouldn't a reseller be like a dealer/broker, who sells the Authorize.net payment system through an external gateway (your branded or whatnot payment system)? So you're buying the right to package and sell the Authorize.net product as your own or in some variation of.

Comment: http://www.authorize.net/solutions/resellersolutions/resellerprogram/ describes the program, and [this PDF](http://www.authorize.net/files/ServiceSelection.pdf) will probably help explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a "real" or, more appropriately, a live Authorize.Net account, you will get a new API Login and Transaction Key. If you programmed your software well you will simply need to swap out these values and everything will continue to work with your live account. You will be able to get your new API Login and Transaction key from the control panel that you get which will be identical to the one which you got with your developer account. Basically, the live account you get from a reseller will work the same as the one you used for development except you will incur fees for its use.